# Django eager loading in many to many

Tags: django, orm, inner-join, django-orm, eager-loading

Those are many models

```
class FacultyMember(models.Model):
    # some attributes

class Publication(models.Model):
    # some attributes
    author = models.ManyToManyField(FacultyMember, blank=True)

class Project(models.Model):
    # some attributes
    researchers = models.ManyToManyField(FacultyMember, blank=True)
```

And I want to get FacultyMember with all related project and publication with eager loading.

I try some thing like following code

```
FacultyMember.objects.filter(
    pk=id,
    first_name=first_name,
    last_name=last_name
).select_related('project_set').select_related('publication_set')
```

However it do not working.

How to join related field in django orm with eager loading.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Manytomany uses prefetch_related;

```
FacultyMember.objects.filter(
pk=id,
first_name=first_name,
last_name=last_name
).prefetch_related('project_set').prefetch_related('publication_set')
```

Refer here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related